# Позднее изменение параметра в Behavior

Tags: c#, avalonia

Использую в Avalonia к дереву Behavior. Нужен мне SelectedItem:

```
            <TreeView Name="NodesTreeView" Items="{Binding TreeViewItemNodes}">
                <TreeView.DataTemplates>
                    <TreeDataTemplate DataType="customs:NodeElementExpanse"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto, 8, *">
                            <avalonia:MaterialIcon Grid.Column="0"
                                                   Kind="{Binding Icon}"
                                                   IsVisible="{Binding Icon, Converter={x:Static ObjectConverters.IsNotNull}}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </TreeDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.DataTemplates>
                <Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <treeViews:TreeViewSingleSelectionCommandBehavior
                        Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=NodesTreeView}" />
                </Interaction.Behaviors>
            </TreeView>
```

Сам Behavior

```
public class TreeViewSingleSelectionCommandBehavior : Behavior<TreeView>
    {
        public static readonly StyledProperty<ICommand> CommandProperty =
            AvaloniaProperty.Register<TreeViewSingleSelectionCommandBehavior, ICommand>(nameof(Command), default, true);

        public static readonly StyledProperty<object> CommandParameterProperty =
            AvaloniaProperty.Register<TreeViewSingleSelectionCommandBehavior, object>(nameof(CommandParameter), default, true);

        public object CommandParameter
        {
            get => GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
            set => SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
        }

        public ICommand Command
        {
            get => GetValue(CommandProperty);
            set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            if (AssociatedObject != null)
            {
                AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChangedUp;
            }
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            if (AssociatedObject != null)
            {
                AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChangedUp;
            }

            base.OnDetaching();
        }

        private void OnSelectionChangedUp(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           if (CommandParameter != null)
            {
                Command?.Invoke(CommandParameter);
            }
        }
```

Вопрос такой: при первом событии CommandParameter будет null, но в самом Дереве в свойстве SelectedItem правильный выбранный элемент. А если еще раз сработает, то будет прошлый выбранный элемент, не новый. Я предполагаю событие срабатывает быстрее чем само изменение CommandParameter. Никто не сталкивался с такой темой? В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем вам этот `Behavior`? Почему бы просто не прибиндить свойство `SelectedItem` и не вызывать нужный код в сеттере? Ведь если сеттер вызван, значит значение изменилось, верно? А не вот это вот всё.

```xml
<TreeView SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNode}" .../>
```

```
private MyDataClass _selectedNode;

public MyDataClass SelectedNode
{
    get => _selectedNode;
    set
    {
        _selectedNode = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(); // INPC
        OnSelectedNodeChanged();
    }
}

private void OnSelectedNodeChanged()
{
    // здесь код, который нужно выполнить при изменении свойства
    // свойство SelectedNode содержит актуальные данные
}
```

Comment: Да, можно. Но не решает проблемы.

Comment: @AleksandrNikolaev если null, то игнорируйте значение. Опишите подробнее, что происходит если использовать мой способ.

Comment: Ваша идея должна работать на 100%. Но и вызывать метод в сетере, как я слышал, не самая хорошая практика.
Имею ввиду, что  не решает проблемы с поведением. В будущем на что либо другое подписка нужна будет, и ошибка снова всплывет

Comment: @AleksandrNikolaev _Но и вызывать метод в сетере, как я слышал, не самая хорошая практика._ - кто сказал такую глупость? А ничего что сеттер сам по себе - это метод? В сеттере не принято выполнять долгие операции, в остальном делайте в сеттерах что угодно.